# jQuery highlight all terms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to highlight search terms but it doesn't split the words. Two words take as a one string and highlights only the string as is.

In the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eayan/) you can see that "Windows XP" is highlighted but not "Windows". What should I do so the both words are highlighted?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

          $('p,a').highlight('Windows XP');

});
```

Thanks for you answers but I think you guys don't understand. The search term is taken from the input field so it changes. It won't be Windows XP always, it can be "sun on the beach" and I want all words to be highlighted not just "sun"

I updated the demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/eayan/12/

Comment: Your demo fiddle seems to be not working.

Comment: try firefox or different browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should highlight the whole string and words inside.

```
var searchterm = "Windows XP";
var tohighlight = searchterm.split(" ");
tohighlight.push(searchterm);
$("p,a").highlight(tohighlight);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the plugin's documentation (available [here](http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html)):

> You can highlight more than one text at once by running highlight with an array of terms as a first attribute. It's much faster than running the highlight function several times.
>
> `$("body p").highlight(["jQuery", "highlight", "plugin"]);`

This means that you can simply use:

```
$('p,a').highlight(['Windows XP', 'Windows']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you get your string with

```
var s = $('#myInput').val();
```

do

```
s.split(' ').forEach(function(token){
    $('p,a').highlight(token);
});
```

or

```
$("body p").highlight(s.split(' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you are searching for this:

```
 var term = $('#q').val();
 $.each(term.split(" "),function(i,v){
     $('p,a').highlight(v);
 });
```